# Sorting <td> by id?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table

I am trying to sort the **td** tag in a table by it ids. 
I have the Below code

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th id="dv_8">COMPANY NAME</th>
    <th id="dv_6">CONTACT 1</th>
    <th id="dv_1">CONTACT 2</th>
    <th id="dv_3">CONTACT 3</th>
    <th id="dv_2">FAX</th>
    <th id="dv_9">WILAYAT</th>
    <th id="dv_5">CUSTOMER SEGMENT</th>
    <th id="dv_10">FLCODE</th>
    <th id="dv_7">Date Added</th>
    <th id="dv_4">QNR Status</th>
</tr>
```

I want the sort the  so that the output is

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th id="dv_1">CONTACT 2</th>
    <th id="dv_2">FAX</th>
    <th id="dv_3">CONTACT 3</th>
    <th id="dv_4">QNR Status</th>
    <th id="dv_5">CUSTOMER SEGMENT</th>
    <th id="dv_6">CONTACT 1</th>
    <th id="dv_7">Date Added</th>
    <th id="dv_8">COMPANY NAME</th>
    <th id="dv_9">WILAYAT</th>
    <th id="dv_10">FLCODE</th>
</tr>
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: What's missing is the code you've tried so far. Where's it?

Comment: You need to try things yourself first. Show some code you've tried here. We're not going to do it all for you.

Comment: please post your missing code and for which purpose you want to sort it?

Comment: Are these dynamically generated? If so, please post any existing code.

Comment: Why can't you just output the table in the right order to begin with? Is it the output of a database or is it a static HTML file? Do you want the user to be able to change the sort order?

Comment: Downvote won't help man.. At least reply in comments :-)

Comment: Dear Guys, I cant post the entire code its 653 lines. Thats why i posted the thing thats necessary. I apologize if i posted it in a wrong manner. Thanks you @VisioN for the quick reply. the jQuery method worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain JavaScript you may do it with:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('th')).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id.replace('dv_', '') - b.id.replace('dv_', '');
}).forEach(function(e) {
    e.parentNode.appendChild(e);
});
```

Or if you use jQuery:

```
$('table th').get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id.replace('dv_', '') - b.id.replace('dv_', '');
}).forEach(function(e) {
    e.parentNode.appendChild(e);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/b4Ngj/

Comment: You are a good human being.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TinySort plugin.. I use it for sorting by Id.. my syntax is something like

```
$('table > tr').tsort('th',{order:'desc',attr:'id'});
```

Link of plugin : http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Comment: Thanks Rahul for trying, i didnt down voted anyone.